# Sulfuric acid recovery

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I know sulfuric acid is an important catalyzer and is used in various processes. My question is, how do I recover the remaining sulfuric acid? It will be impure, and I don't know how to do the "standard" procedure (is there one?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laboratory, nobody cares. It's too cheap to care about.

In industry, other catalysts are usually used (heterogeneous ones).

Comment: Of course in industry sulfuric acid is used! In all cases where some washing with water is needed anyway, there is no reason not to use sulfuric  or hydrochloric acid.

Comment: @Georg it is another reagent to transport, store, use and dispose. It costs.